# TomCat jBoss Application

Tags: session, tomcat, jboss

I have a .war(web app) deployed on Tomcat server. I have another application on  jBoss server.
The application on the Tomcat is the start point and a jsp on the jBoss server gets called from the Tomcat app. Then I am planning to set a session on the jBoss server app and when I am done my processing on the jBoss I will send back the control to the app on Tomcat.

The question is 
1) Is the model that I mentioned above doable?
2) If it is can I invalidate the session on Tomcat server once the control comes back from the jBoss server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  If the process on JBoss is long running, you might want to use JMS to handle you requests asynchronously...

Comment: Well I am having a Twitter app on jBoss server and I am having a simple web app on Tomcat application. I cannot invalidate the session on the jBoss 'cos I need to do some checks on the Tomcat server. Not sure if that is even possible

Comment: @sv1, but what are you trying to do? Retrieve Twitter info on Jboss and return it to Tomcat?

Comment: Well I have a Twitter application which authenticates users on the jBoss server and when the authentication is completed and when the control is back on the Tomcat app - I will need to ask the user if he would like to signoff from his Twitter account. If the user clicks "Yes" I will have to invalidate the user