# Tomcat or JBoss server for a Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss

This might be duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668042/jboss-vs-tomcat-again) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973842/tomcat-jboss-application).

I have a java application in which i am using JAX-WS (WEB SERVICES). and many other features in it like [apache-commons utils.](http://commons.apache.org/)

1. My application is swing application, that connects to my server code
   and uploads and downloads, and sync files with the server. my
   database is mysql.
2. I have compiled my server code and created a .WAR file. i deployed 
   that .WAR   (containing all the required libraries for my server 
   side application) file  on a JBoss server and its working fine.
3. Now my Management says me to why use JBoss instead of Tomcat, which
   easy to manage and setup on a linux server. actualy they have a
   linux server which supports tomcat, but not JBoss. so they said to
   me to deploy on Tomcat on Linux Server. I installed and configured
   tomcat on my windows and deployed a .WAR file. and also created
   virtual directory for my resources its working fine[but not tested
   completely]
4. My Application does not have EJB so I think that Tomcat is good enough.
5. Please suggest me is it fine to use Tomcat instead of JBoss server,
   I am worried if it may get problems in the future, or it might not
   support features of my application in future or after complete testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JBoss uses Tomcat under the hood to host war applications anyway.

Using Tomcat for you war application instead of JBoss should be perfectly fine.
Any commons-jars that you are using can be downloaded from http://commons.apache.org/. Put them in your lib directory and you should be good to go. Most apache commons libraries should allready be included with Tomcat though, you'll have to check.

PS:
JAX-WS is standard in the latest JDK6 updates. If your using a earlier version of the JDK then just download the JAX-WS jars. The standard reference implementation from Oracle/Sun can be downloaded from here http://jax-ws.java.net/

Comment: It used to be true that JBoss embedded Tomcat directly, but I believe recent JBoss versions (5+) use JBoss Web (http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb), which may have started life as Tomcat, but would probably be unrecognizable as such now.

Comment: Mmm I never knew that. Good to know. It seems that it is still pretty much Tomcat under the hood mostly. To be more specific Tomcat 6.0 http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/arch.html

Answer (score 3):

Do you have EJB? JBoss comes with its implementation of the EJB JSR specification.

For Tomcat, you require plugins like openEJB.

Many application servers use Tomcat internally as its Servlet container. But for compliance to JavaEE standards, most would choose a JBoss application server over Tomcat anyday.

Note that JBoss 7 Application Server Web Profile is certified.

Tomcat functions well as a plain vanilla Servlet container. Many enterprises when using Tomcat, couple it with Proxy and HTTPD servers for security and load balancing reasons.

Comment: No i have no EJB in my application. and thats why no i think tomcat is good enough for my application.

Comment: @Ashgar JBoss (and any Java EE server) also has JPA, JSF, CDI, JTA and many other things. It's not just about EJB.